# How to access the project version from within Gradle Kotlin DSL expressions?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I have a Gradle 5.3 build script using Kotlin DSL, similar to this:

```
plugins {
    `kotlin-dsl`
    `java-library`
}

group = "my.company"
version = "1.2.3"
```

Here, `version=` resolves to `org.gradle.api.Project.setVersion`.

Now, farther down, I'd like to do this (porting from a Groovy DSL build file):

```
tasks.named<Jar>("jar") {
    manifest {
        attributes(
            "Product-Version" to version
        )
    }
}
```

Here, `version` resolves to `AbstractArchiveTask.getVersion` -- not what I want (and also deprecated)!

Figuring I could use Kotlin's [qualified `this`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/this-expressions.html#qualified), I tried to use

```
"${this@Project.version}"
```

instead (NB: the extra string wrapping gets rid of an additional type error), but I get `Unresolved reference: @Project` now.

How can I access the project version from within a Kotlin DSL expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Gradle script doesn't seem to be nested inside `Project` but instead delegates accessors to its relevant properties. In fact, the top-level `this` is of type `Build_gradle`.

When those accessors are shadowed, variable `project` can be used; that is,

```
project.version
```

solves the issue at hand. As an alternative,

```
this@Build_gradle.version
```

is also valid but less readable.